# The multi-part identifier "inserted.Id" could not be bound while creating trigger

Tags: sql-server

I am trying to create a trigger on a table in SQL Server 2012, but it is giving an error like below

"The multi-part identifier "inserted.Id" could not be bound",

The query I am executing is

```
CREATE TRIGGER dbo.[TR_t_documents_InsertUpdateDelete] ON 

dbo.[t_documents] AFTER INSERT, UPDATE, DELETE
AS
BEGIN 

    UPDATE dbo.[t_documents]
    SET dbo.[t_documents].[UpdatedAt] = CONVERT(DATETIMEOFFSET, SYSUTCDATETIME()) 
    FROM
        INSERTED
    WHERE inserted.[Id] = dbo.[t_documents].[Id]
END
```

The same is executing successfully in SQL Server 2014.

Can anyone help me why this is happening in SQL server 2012?

Comment: What collation is your database using? Does this query work if you use upper case for `INSERTED`?

Comment: why would you need this as an `after delete`? the row won't even exist at that point.

Comment: also, that could potentially be the problem?  the inserted table doesn't exist in a delete accourding to https://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/Aa214435%28v=SQL.80%29.aspx?f=255&MSPPError=-2147217396

Comment: @Kritner If that were the case, wouldn't the error occur on the `FROM` line rather than the `WHERE` clause?

Comment: @DavidG guess that's true

Comment: @DavidG Yes, it's an issue with the collation. In my SQL Server2012 Database has Case Sensitive collation where as in 2014 server has case insensitive, When I changed capital letters INSERTED to inserted it executed successfully. Thank you very much :)

Answer (score 12, accepted):

This is due to the collation you have for the database. In this case, you are using a case sensitive collation, so the table names need to be consistently. For the virtual trigger tables, these need to be in upper case, for example:

```
CREATE TRIGGER dbo.[TR_t_documents_InsertUpdateDelete] ON 

dbo.[t_documents] AFTER INSERT, UPDATE, DELETE
AS
BEGIN 

    UPDATE dbo.[t_documents]
    SET dbo.[t_documents].[UpdatedAt] = CONVERT(DATETIMEOFFSET, SYSUTCDATETIME()) 
    FROM
        INSERTED
    WHERE INSERTED.[Id] = dbo.[t_documents].[Id]
    --    ^^^^^^^^
    --      THIS!
END
```